# PHP foreach/else issue

Tags: php, foreach

```
foreach($cases['rows'] as $i => $item) {
    foreach($array as $key => $val) {
        if($item['status'] == $key) {
            echo $val;
        }
    }
}
```

Right now this code functions, but if `$item['status'] != $key` it echoes nothing.  I've tried to add an `else` statement after the `if` statement except it prints it tens of times.

How can I achieve this functionality?  I want it to print `$item['status']` if `$item['status'] != $key`

Help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example of `$cases['Rows'];`?

Comment: Post some example data

Comment: you have to show more, because if it works for !=, it works for ==, it comes from somewhere else

Comment: Sounds like you might want to put the `if` statement outside the inner loop.

Comment: if you want to print $item['status'] so 'echo $item['status'];' not 'echo $val;'

Comment: So... This code works, but a version you're not showing us doesn't work?  Can you maybe share the non-working version so we can help?

Comment: I have an array of key/values (ex: 'NT' => 'Not Taken') and an array of data.  If the `$item['status']` is equal to one of the values in the `$array` I want it to show the full value, not the abbreviation (i.e. 'Not Taken').

Comment: @David the echoing of `$val` works but I want to echo $item['status'] if the condition is not true (which is often).

Comment: @user3817533: How does an `else` block not accomplish this?  I'm not seeing what the issue is here.

Comment: The outer foreach loop can not be ended because other data is being echoed out after this.  This data is being shown in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I understand the question you have two arrays:

1. An array containing different abbreviations and their full meaning.
2. Another multidimensional array containing arrays which again contain status-abbreviations.

To echo the full meaning instead of the abbreviations:

```
$abbreviations = array('NT' => 'Not taken',
                       'N/A' => 'Not available');

$data = array(array('status' => 'NT'),
              array('status' => 'N/A'));

foreach($data as $item) {
    if(array_key_exists($item['status'], $abbreviations)) {
        echo $abbreviations[$item['status']] . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo $item['status'] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Result:

> Not taken
>
> Not available

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$test = null;
foreach($cases['rows'] as $i => $item) {
    foreach($array as $key => $val) {
        if($item['status'] == $key) {
            echo $val;
        }
        else {
            $test = $val;
        }
    }
}
if($test != null) {
    echo $test//Or whatever you want to display
}
```

Comment: This appends the last value in my array of key/values to the end of every row.

Comment: I changed the `echo $test` to `echo $item['status']` and now it works fine EXCEPT it tacks on the key to the end of each row.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info regarding the type of data in both arrays, I would suggest you to try:

- `!($item['status'] == $key)` deny the correct statement
- `$item['status'] !== $key` try also checking the same type (test this also with the equal statement to see if you get the results you expect)